# loop on np.loadtxt name is not defined

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list on a file called

```
lista=[ca4227,fe4383,fe5015,fe5270,fe5406,fe5709,g4300,hb,hb_p,hda,hdf,hga,hgf,mgb,mgb1,mgb2,nad,OII3727,oiii_1,oiii_2]
```

each name is a file which  contains  a table:

```
{ 1   -5.8231   1.1227   8.20      
  2   -5.3294   1.0801   8.44     
..    ..         ..      ..    
  5   0.1008   1.7203   4.77    

  11   undef3   undef3   undef3}
```

with many undef3 so I would like to read the 4 colums as follow

```
import numpy as np    
file1=np.loadtxt('lista',unpack=True, usecols=[0],dtype=list)    
for i in range(0,len(file1)):
   sp+str(i),index+str(i),err+str(i),sn+str(i)=np.loadtxt(file1[i],unpack=True,usecols=[0,1,2,3], dtype=list)
```

and I got this error: "name 'sp' is not defined- while doing it individually it works, obviouslly I will remove undef3 later.

Comment: What is the value of `file1`?  Try the 2nd `loadtxt` without `unpack` and make sure you understand the resulting array.  Oh, and cleanup the indenting.

Comment: Where do you initialize `sp`, `index` and so on.  Until you get it right separate the `loadtxt` line from task of accumulating results in some sort of variable.